# Notification in the document store in iCloud

Tags: macos, cocoa, notifications, icloud

Which notification should I observe when the data in the document store in iCloud has being changed?

In Key-Values store, there is a  `NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification`. However in document store, I don't find a notification like that. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Called whenever the application reads data from the file system

- (BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError

this method method called when data updated on iCloud so u can push local notification in this method. this method also called when u save some data on iCloud using this method

// Called whenever the application (auto)saves the content of a note

- (id)contentsForType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError

so we need to set some variable or condition for local notification.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the document store as the Key Value Store.
You have to set up a `NSMetadataQuery`. You can find more info on the Apple Docs.